# How to close window opened by window.open()

Tags: javascript

My case is:
1) I open popup window by window.open
2) Opened window redirects to authorization service, then it 
a) prolong current session and redirects to origin domain 
or
b) remain on auth service domain and asks user to enter password
3) Pop-up window should be closed

In 1 - 2a - 3 case everything is well.
But in 2b case there is a problem - window.onload doesn't work. It is because of cross domain security.

So, question. How can I close opened window in any case? Even it was redirected to another domain? 
Why I don't have ability to manage window opened by me?

```
var new_window = window.open(path, 'window', 'height=100,width=50');
new_window.onload = function() {
    new_window.close();
}
```

P.S. iframes cannot be used due to auth service prohibition

Comment: you can't. you have to rely on the page to close itself or to redirect back to your server.

Comment: In case 2b, doesn't it redirect to the original domain after the password was entered correctly?